# Spark in blender motor

Tags: motor, repair, appliances

I was trying to repair a blender whose speed buttons were not working. I thought of removing the speed regulating circuit altogether and directly connect power to the motor. Now, when I run the motor I see sparks in it. I understand some initial sparking may be normal, but is a continued sparking also normal? I am not sure if there were sparks before removing the circuit, I never ran the blender with its bottom removed earlier. Is it safe to use this blender now?

I have a small clip here: https://vid.me/VI2n

Comment: Yes, there usually is some sparking with any brushed motor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is normal for brushed motors, such as the universal motors common in household appliances, to spark some, I would check the brushes for excess wear, due to how continuous the arc in your motor is.

(The sparking is not hazardous under normal conditions -- the only time it'd cause a problem is if you tried to run the blender in a room full of gasoline fumes!)